# Create IAM Role dynamically per application users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to create AWS IAM role per my application users. 1 user to have 1 IAM role and the number of users can be like 100,000 users.

I do so that I can revoke STS temporary credentials when the user logout from my application. or revoke s3 presiged url.

Is there some limitation to create such large number of role in AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of IAM roles is limited to [1000 per account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-limits.html#reference_iam-limits-entities).

You would have to contact AWS support to try to increase the limit, but I doubt you would get the limit increased to 100,000. I think better way would be to rethink your design.

For example, using [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) you could work with federated identities to which would would assign IAM roles. This way you could have fewer roles, and a user login out he/she will not have access to your AWS resources. To regain access, your uses would have to login using Cognito again.